# Connecting to AS400 server from java code through SFTP

Tags: java, sftp, ibm-midrange, jsch

I am trying to write a `java` code which will connect to a AS400 server through `SFTP` and transfer files.
I am using Jsch for `SFTP`. I have entered user_name, password and host-url to connect.

But I discovered that AS400 server is refusing connection. Is there any setting I need  while connecting or any setting for privileges on AS400 ?

Please suggest a way to use SFTP to connect to AS400.

Answer (score 4):

The IBM i (AS/400) does not have an SSH daemon installed by default.

The Midrange Wiki has some information about [Setting up an iSeries SSHD server](http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/SSH#Setting_up_an_iSeries_SSHD_server).

---

The [**JTOpen/IBM Toolbox for Java**](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) library may be a better solution for interfacing with the system.  There are [`Access`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fpage1.htm) classes that support file transfer.